# How to get height of the soft keyboard without using "adjustResize"?

Tags: android, ime

This question has been asked several time but good answers to this problem always use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in `manifest.xml`

As I need my view to not move when the keyboard shows up, I'm looking for a solution that not require to resize the layout.

Thanks for your suggestion.